# zend validator is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am creating a Zend form.

when i have submit the form then error messages are not showing. It seems that validator is never triggered. This is my code:

> $form = new Zend_Form;
>
> ```
>   $form->setMethod('POST')
>    ->setAttrib('Name','pwdfrm')       
>          ->setAttrib('Id','pwdfrm');
>
>      $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
>   $email->setLabel('Email :')
>       ->setDecorators($this->textbox)
>       ->setRequired(true)
>       ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
>       ->addErrorMessage('In valid');
>
>           $form->addElements(array($email, 
>               new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit',array(
>                   'decorators' => $this->buttonDecorators,
>                   'Label'=>'Submit',
>               )),
>               ));
>
>   $form->setDecorators(array(   
>      'FormElements',
>     array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table','align'=>'center','class'=>'tbcss','width'=>'100%','border'=>1)),
>
> 'Form',   
>      ));
> ```
>
> $this->view->assign('form',$form);
>           $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
>
> if($request->isPost())
>          {
>              print_r($request->getPost());
>          }

And this is my decorators:

> public $textbox = array(
>
> ```
> 'ViewHelper',     
>   'FormElements',   
>   array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td', 'class' =>
> ```
>
> 'element','width'=>'43%','valign'=>'top')),
>
> ```
>   'Errors',
>
> array(array('closeLabel' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td','closeOnly' => true, 'placement' =>'prepend')),    
>      'Label',
> ```
>
> array(array('openLabel' =>'HtmlTag'),array('tag' =>'td', >'openOnly'=>true,'align'=>'right','valign'=>'top','width'=>'15%')),
>
> ```
> array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),   
>  );
> ```
>
> public $buttonDecorators = array(
>
> ```
>     'ViewHelper',
>     'Errors',
>   'FormElements',
>     array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'td','align'=>'center','colspan'=>'2')),
>     array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
> );
> ```

can anyone help me plz.

Comment: I don't see you calling isValid ($_POST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed

```
 // Check method/data validitiy
   if( !$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) ) {
      return;
    }
```

Good Luck :-)